# Bootstrap navbar fly in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to an achieve an effect like the one demonstrated here:
http://templateocean.com/stamp/image-bg/1-home-style-one/index.html

The navbar flies in after you scroll to a certain position.

I used this script as a baseline:

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});
```

css:

```
@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
       /* display: none;*/
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This changes the navbar height. I played around with the 'display:' parameter and it works to an extent; however, the navbar was popping up without the nice slide effect.

I tried to use this script: 
https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

so I changed the original code to:

```
(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
       $("#navbar-top").toggle("slide");
    } else {
        $("#navbar-top").toggle("slide");
    }
});
```

Now, however, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': 2
>   arguments required, but only 1 present.custom.js:22 (anonymous
>   function)

What I am doing wrong? Do I have to really use JS for the slide effect? Can I use some other CSS attributes to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Are you using jQuery and jQueryUI? This example that only uses Bootstrap and jQuery may help: http://bootply.com/JsVw8y6nYP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you load jquery before the other js scripts.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue!